# Error while opening jupyter notebook in python 3.9.1

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm facing problem while trying to open jupyter notebook in python 3.9.1, the error is given at last, Plz someone can help me...This problem really tired me.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> pip install jupyter


----------

Requirement already satisfied: jupyter in c:\users\saquib\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: qtconsole in c:\users\saquib\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from jupyter) (5.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: notebook in c:\users\saquib\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from jupyter) (6.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: ipywidgets in c:\users\saquib\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from jupyter) (7.6.3)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-console in c:\users\saquib\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from jupyter) (6.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: ipykernel in c:\users\saquib\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from jupyter) (5.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: nbconvert in c:\users\saquib\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from jupyter) (6.0.7)
Requirement already satisfied: traitlets>=4.1.0 in c:\users\saquib\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from ipykernel->jupyter) (5.0.5)
Requirement already satisfied: tornado>=4.2 in c:\users\saquib\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from ipykernel->jupyter) (6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython>=5.0.0 in c:\users\saquib\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from ipykernel->jupyter) (7.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-client in c:\users\saquib\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from ipykernel->jupyter) (6.1.12)
Requirement already satisfied: jedi>=0.16 in c:\users\saquib\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel->jupyter) (0.18.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pickleshare in c:\users\saquib\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel->jupyter) (0.7.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments in c:\users\saquib\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel->jupyter) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator in c:\users\saquib\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel->jupyter) (4.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: backcall in c:\users\saquib\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel->jupyter) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in c:\users\saquib\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel->jupyter) (0.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=18.5 in c:\program files\python39\lib\site-packages (from ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel->jupyter) (49.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: prompt-toolkit!=3.0.0,!=3.0.1,<3.1.0,>=2.0.0 in c:\users\saquib\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel->jupyter) (3.0.18)
Requirement already satisfied: parso<0.9.0,>=0.8.0 in c:\users\saquib\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from jedi>=0.16->ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel->jupyter) (0.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: wcwidth in c:\users\saquib\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from prompt-toolkit!=3.0.0,!=3.0.1,<3.1.0,>=2.0.0->ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel->jupyter) (0.2.5)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython-genutils in c:\users\saquib\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from traitlets>=4.1.0->ipykernel->jupyter) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: widgetsnbextension~=3.5.0 in c:\users\saquib\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from ipywidgets->jupyter) (3.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyterlab-widgets>=1.0.0 in c:\users\saquib\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from ipywidgets->jupyter) (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: nbformat>=4.2.0 in c:\users\saquib\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from ipywidgets->jupyter) (5.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4 in c:\users\saquib\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from nbformat>=4.2.0->ipywidgets->jupyter) (3.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-core in c:\users\saquib\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from nbformat>=4.2.0->ipywidgets->jupyter) (4.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.11.0 in c:\users\saquib\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4->nbformat>=4.2.0->ipywidgets->jupyter) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.4.0 in c:\users\saquib\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4->nbformat>=4.2.0->ipywidgets->jupyter) (20.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyrsistent>=0.14.0 in c:\users\saquib\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4->nbformat>=4.2.0->ipywidgets->jupyter) (0.17.3)
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in c:\program files\python39\lib\site-packages (from notebook->jupyter) (2.11.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyzmq>=17 in c:\users\saquib\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from notebook->jupyter) (22.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: Send2Trash>=1.5.0 in c:\users\saquib\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from notebook->jupyter) (1.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: argon2-cffi in c:\users\saquib\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from notebook->jupyter) (20.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: terminado>=0.8.3 in c:\users\saquib\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from notebook->jupyter) (0.9.3)
Requirement already satisfied: prometheus-client in c:\users\saquib\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from notebook->jupyter) (0.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in c:\users\saquib\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from jupyter-client->ipykernel->jupyter) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32>=1.0 in c:\users\saquib\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from jupyter-core->nbformat>=4.2.0->ipywidgets->jupyter) (300)
Requirement already satisfied: pywinpty>=0.5 in c:\program files\python39\lib\site-packages (from terminado>=0.8.3->notebook->jupyter) (0.5.7)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.0.0 in c:\users\saquib\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from argon2-cffi->notebook->jupyter) (1.14.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\users\saquib\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from cffi>=1.0.0->argon2-cffi->notebook->jupyter) (2.20)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in c:\program files\python39\lib\site-packages (from jinja2->notebook->jupyter) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: nbclient<0.6.0,>=0.5.0 in c:\users\saquib\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from nbconvert->jupyter) (0.5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: testpath in c:\users\saquib\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from nbconvert->jupyter) (0.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: defusedxml in c:\users\saquib\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from nbconvert->jupyter) (0.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pandocfilters>=1.4.1 in c:\users\saquib\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from nbconvert->jupyter) (1.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: entrypoints>=0.2.2 in c:\users\saquib\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from nbconvert->jupyter) (0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyterlab-pygments in c:\users\saquib\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from nbconvert->jupyter) (0.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: mistune<2,>=0.8.1 in c:\users\saquib\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from nbconvert->jupyter) (0.8.4)
Requirement already satisfied: bleach in c:\users\saquib\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from nbconvert->jupyter) (3.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: nest-asyncio in c:\users\saquib\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from nbclient<0.6.0,>=0.5.0->nbconvert->jupyter) (1.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: async-generator in c:\users\saquib\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from nbclient<0.6.0,>=0.5.0->nbconvert->jupyter) (1.10)
Requirement already satisfied: webencodings in c:\users\saquib\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from bleach->nbconvert->jupyter) (0.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in c:\users\saquib\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from bleach->nbconvert->jupyter) (20.9)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.0.2 in c:\users\saquib\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from packaging->bleach->nbconvert->jupyter) (2.4.7)
Requirement already satisfied: qtpy in c:\users\saquib\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from qtconsole->jupyter) (1.9.0)

 - PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> jupyter notebook

----------------------------------------

jupyter : The term 'jupyter' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the
path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ jupyter notebook
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (jupyter:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: This might not be related, but have you tried running the same commands outside of the *system32/* directory?

Comment: Good callout on that, Jacob.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this:
python -m notebook

Or if it’s Python 3 try:
python3 -m notebook

I’m not sure if this is the solution, but I know this is the command for Windows to open Jupyter Notebook.